# How to route Client OpenVPN in LAN on Mac OS X OpenVPN Server

Tags: osx, openvpn

I have configured an OpenVPN Server on my Mac OS X High Sierra.

I did that using Easy RSA 3.04 which I had downloaded from [github](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/releases), and Tunnelblick to start and stop the server.

My LAN network is: 192.168.100.0/24, the Server IP is: 192.168.100.10 and the Gateway is: 192.168.100.1. The VPN network is the OpenVPN default 10.8.0.0/24 with server 10.8.0.1

"All works" but after the connection, the client can reach the Server LAN. In the OpenVPN server.conf, I put the following:

```
dev tun         
proto udp
port 1194       
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0
client-config-dir /OpenVPN/ccd
push "route 192.186.100.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.1 1"
client-to-client
push "route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-auth ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify crl.pem
status-version 3
verb 1
```

Then I have abilitated the forwarding:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

And after server connection the, results of the command:

```
netstat -rn
```

is:

```
Routing tables
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.100.1      UGSc           92      485     en0
10.8/24            10.8.0.1           UGSc            0        0   utun1
10.8.0.1           10.8.0.1           UH              1        0   utun1
```

It seems that something is not correct in the routing of the OpenVPN server, but after several tests nothing works.

Answer (score -1):

You're pushing the local LAN route to the clients; that is why they can reach it.

Comment: Hello lewis. It would improve your answer, if you could recommend what the OP could change in order to get the desired result.

Comment: OK, sorry for the late response.
With this setting the VPN client can reach any LAN device with their LAN IP, apart the server itself that response only with their VPN IP 10.8.0.1, instead 192.168.100.10.